# Flash cs5 as3 font embed conflict

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fonts, embed, conflict

I really hope someone can help me with this. I have two dynamic text boxes on stage - strap1 and strap2 respectively.

Both text boxes use the same font; just different styles. e.g strap1 is Arial regular, strap2 is arial black.

In order to get a good anti-alias, I have embeded both fonts. The problem is that the top font overwrites the second. So instead of strap1 being arial normal and strap2 arial black, both textboxes are arial normal.

Is there anyway to avoid or fix this conflict? i am using as3, CS5.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't recreate this in a new document with two text fields on the stage.  Is there something else going on? What do you see in the embed window?

Comment: Thanks for the response shanethehat. I'm not quite sure I understand your question, but I see font name, family, style and selected characters/glyphs in the embed window.

Comment: Are you sure you've set the embedded fonts to be Arial Black and Arial Regular as opposed to just embedding Arial twice?

Try creating a fresh project with two simple dynamic text boxes and embed the fonts making sure you've set both to respective weights. Can you post a screenshot of your embed window.

Comment: When you click embed you should see a list of all the fonts you're using, and both styles of Arial should be listed separately.  Make sure you're checking the character-set boxes for both styles.

Comment: I am not allowed to post images. I have thoroughly checked my embed window and it appears just as shanethehat has described. i also selected all for character ranges. I am using CS5

Comment: Hello guys, any breakthrough, I'm still stuck with this

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that both fonts are given unique names, such as "Arial-normal" and "Arial-black". Chances are, they are currently the same, so at compile time one is replacing the other.

Answer (score 0):

Was this file ever save or used with Flash CS4? I've found out the hard way that a file originally authored in CS4 will have serious font problems when opened in CS5. A solution I found for that was to save it out as CS4, from within CS5. Then you should be able to finish the project.